# What does "coherent wave function of a macroscopic body" mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

What is meant by the "coherent wave function of a macroscopic body"? I found this phrase in [a paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02717926) on QM, but am unfamiliar with the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of the exact context of your work, but anyway, only case that I recall having read on "coherent wave functions", was in the quantum mechanical study of harmonic oscillators, where the states (wavefunctions) that minimized the uncertainty between position and momentum of the oscillator, without undermining Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, were then referred to as "coherent". Maybe "coherent" here is used to put emphasis on the fact that such states are close to the classical behaviour of harmonic oscillators, I am not sure about the exact reason underlying the choice of name.

For further details, I recommend the wiki page on [coherent states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states).

Comment: Thank you :) let me look into it further and try to relate it to this.

Comment: Haha yes I have. But I am not sure which one to choose as all three have been equally helpful in some way. :)

Comment: I have :) but I am open to more viewpoints. You never know what you get :) thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

'Coherent wave function of macroscopic body' usually refers to wave functions such as found in superconductors, superfluids and Bose-Einstein condensates. Usually, owing to numerous sources of decoherence caused by coupling to environment, it is formidably difficult to maintain the coherence of a wave function describing a macroscopic body. By 'coherence', it mostly means that the phase of the wave function develops according to Schrodinger equation. There are plenty of papers on this. I'd recommend those by Phil. Anderson written in the 1960s or 1970s. Also, a very nice description can be found in *Feynmann lectures, 3rd Vol, chapter 21 on superconductivity.*

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to the question is that the particles of concern (electrons or atoms) are all in the same single-particle state with the same phase. Of course this is not possible for electrons themselves, but they can form Cooper pairs and then are able to, in a sense, occupy the same single-particle state.

The explanation I have given here is a little oversimplified and really what I mean by single-particle state is associated with with the eigeinvectors of the many-body density matrix and off-diagonal long range order. Leggett's book Quantum Liquids is really clear on this point.

Comment: Let me see if I can get hold of the book and understand it a bit better :) thank you.